# Server and Client Dual Communication IPhone

Tags: iphone

After coding a simple multi player game to be played on the same device  I'm interested in writing a server for the game so it could be played across several devices.

Which technologies do you use to write a server, which allows dual communications between the client and server?

Comment: Please do not deface your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NSStream](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is what you use, it is an abstraction of *sockets.*

an example is [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server), the server is written in python but if you scroll down you can get to the client iPhone code. You can program the server in any language with a socket api.

Comment: I realize that, but NSStream is an abstraction which does make it slightly easier. You are not going to get "dual" communication with webservices. You would have to use "Polling" - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)

Comment: welp, your out of options then!